# How to make If Python statement based on a string input in HTML code

Tags: python, html, web

So I have a value named "Following" in HTML code;

```
<button class="oW_lN oF4XW sqdOP yWX7d">Following</button>
```

How could I make Python perform an action if this value is in the HTML code.

So basically an If statement.

Comment: Your question is incomplete. How are you getting this HTML? Did you write it yourself? Are you making a code to fetch html from some existing page? Or you're the page author trying to get data from a visitor? Also, please provide the code you already have written, and some more information, like which frameworks/libraries you're using

Comment: @Nosko I am getting this via Inspect option from Instagram.

Comment: you have to edit the question and add **all** information I said above to the question itself (not in comment) or it will probably be closed for lack of information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using my crystal ball and the excellent `lxml.html` parser;

```
import lxml.html
doc = lxml.html.fromstring('<button class="oW_lN oF4XW sqdOP yWX7d">Following</button>')

print(doc.xpath("//button/text()")[0])
```

This code will parse the HTML snippet you provided, then find a button in it and print its text.

The results:

```
Following
```